# Si elimino una columna que está siendo usada por un SP, ¿Da error?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, sql

cordial saludo.

Estoy eliminando columnas de una tabla y algunas de estas están siendo llamadas en procedimientos almacenados, mi duda es: si elimino una de esas columnas, ¿se muestra algún tipo de error y no deja eliminar la columna?.

Agradezco la atención prestada.

Comment: Lo probaste? creo que solo te tira error al ejecutar el SP... no anda revisando todo la DB..

Comment: La mejor forma de saberlo es probarlo y opino lo mismo que gbianchi, no deberia darte error al eliminar la columna sino al llamar el SP

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias.

Comment: NO, solo falla eventualmente el SP cuando lo ejecutes